# Google Meet startTimeCode Use, is it possible to lookup form a spreadsheet cell?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been using this code to access attendance for a specific Meet, but I'd like to be able to call the function so it identifies startTime for "today". Is that possible?
I have tried, unsuccessfully, to use code I have found on this site to convert it to an iso string, using the function new Date() to obtain the date and time of "now".
Thank you.
Marcelo

```
function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('SanGabriel')
      .addItem("Curso", 'importCourses')
      .addItem('Asistencia', 'checkAll')
      .addToUi();
} 

    function importCourses() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    teacherId: 'all',
    pageSize: 5
  };
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
  var courses = response.courses;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var courseName = courses[i].name;
    var courseId = courses[i].id;
    insertCourse(courseName, courseId)
  }
}

function insertCourse(courseName, courseId) {
    var spreadsheetName = courseName + "(" + courseId + ")"
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheetName);

    if (yourNewSheet != null) {
        return
    }
    yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
    yourNewSheet.setName(spreadsheetName);
    yourNewSheet.appendRow(['Nombre', 'Email', 'Asistencia'])
    yourNewSheet.setFrozenRows(1)
    var studentNames = getRoster(courseId)["studentNames"]
    var studentEmails = getRoster(courseId)["studentEmails"]
    for (var i = 0; i < studentNames.length; i++) {
      yourNewSheet.appendRow([studentNames[i],studentEmails[i]])
    }
    yourNewSheet.autoResizeColumns(1, 2)
    yourNewSheet.setFrozenColumns(2)
  }

function getRoster(courseId) {
  var studentNames = []
  var studentEmails = []
  var optionalArgs = {
      pageSize: 100
  };
  var response = Classroom.Courses.Students.list(courseId, optionalArgs)
  var students = response.students

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    try {
      studentNames.push(students[i].profile.name.fullName)
      studentEmails.push(students[i].profile.emailAddress)
    } catch (err) {
       return { "studentNames":studentNames, "studentEmails":studentEmails }
   }
 }
}

function checkAll() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 2; i < sheet.length * 100; i++){
    var meetCode = getCleanCode(sheet[0][i])
    // No Meet code given
    if (meetCode == null) {
      break;
    }
    else {
      // check whether each student was present in Meet
      checkMeet(meetCode, i+1);

    }
  }
}

function checkMeet(meetCode, index) {
  // universal settings - static
  var userKey = 'all';
  var applicationName = 'meet';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

//let today = new Date()
//var staringTime = new Date().toISOString();  

  var DateValue = ss.getRange(1, 1).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < sheet.length-1; i++) {
    var emailAddress = sheet[i+1][1]
    var optionalArgs = {
      startTime: "2020-05-12T00:00:00.000Z",
      event_name: "call_ended",
      filters: "identifier==" + emailAddress + ",meeting_code==" + meetCode
    };
    try {
      var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs);
      var activities = response.items;
      if (activities == undefined) {
        markAbsent(ss,i+2,index)
      }
      else {
        markPresent(ss,i+2,index)
      }
      } catch (err) {
        continue
    }
  }
}

function getCleanCode(meetCode) {
  try{
   return meetCode.replace(/-/g, "");
  } catch (err) { return meetCode; }
}

function markAbsent(sheet, i, j) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(i, j);
    cell.setValue("N");
}

function markPresent(sheet, i, j) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(i, j);
    cell.setValue("");
}
```

Comment: A very kind user has suggested the following (I'm not sure how to do that): "use the function new Date() to obtain the date and time of now. In order to use it a a startTime, you need to convert it to an iso string. Sample: var starTime = new Date().toISOString(); " – Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can do it, it's like this:

```
function checkMeet(meetCode, index) {
  // More code...
  // ****
  // ... More code
  for (var i = 0; i < sheet.length-1; i++) {
    var emailAddress = sheet[i+1][1]
    var optionalArgs = {
      startTime: formatStartDate(),
      event_name: "call_ended",
      filters: "identifier==" + emailAddress + ",meeting_code==" + meetCode
    };
    // More code...
    // ****
    // ... More code
  }
}

function formatStartDate(){
  let date = new Date();
  /* We get an offset because toISOString() will convert to UTC
  * therefore, if you are in +/- timezone you'll get a wrong hour
  * and even get the next/previous day 
  */
  const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
  /* In my case I substract(-)
  * but depending in your timezone, you could add(+)
  * date.getTime() +/- (offset*60*1000)
  */
  let offsetDate = new Date(date.getTime() - (offset*60*1000));
  return offsetDate.toISOString();
}
```

***P.S***: I used [these docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list) to have an idea on how to help you.

Comment: Quite marvellous, thank you. That works absolutely perfectly well, 100%

Comment: Thanks to this 200 teachers will not have to use time in attendance tasks; they can have more quality screen-time with their students.

Comment: Thank you once again. I'm now making it available to other schools / school districts in Chile, but of course, if more teachers and schools around the world can use it, well great!